# What is difference between NodeType and ScaleSet in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-service-fabric

Can someone help me out like what's the difference between NodeType and ScaleSet in Azure ServiceFabric

and NodeType contains the Scale set which inturn contains VM's or? how to understand these concepts

Answer (score 0):

nodetype is a service fabric concept. basically a set of identical nodes. it is implemented as a vmss (scale set) in Microsoft Azure. which is basically a set of identical nodes capable of scaling.

> Virtual machine scale sets are an Azure compute resource. You can use
> scale sets to deploy and manage a collection of virtual machines as a
> set. Each node type that you define in an Azure Service Fabric cluster
> sets up exactly one scale set: multiple node types cannot be backed by
> the same scale set and one node type should not be backed by multiple
> scale sets.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-nodetypes

Comment: So each NodeType contains 1ScaleSet and this ScaleSet contains "N" no.of VM's
Am I right?

Comment: like i mentioned in my answer nodetype == scaleset, nodetype is a concept from service fabric. scale set is a concept from Azure